# Pulling 1000+ records from MySQL, need advice

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to pull over a thousand records from a MySQL DB using PHP and due to the long load time I'm curious if there is a better way to write this Query.

```
function PropigateTable($Connection) {
    $SQL = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT `ID`, `LegalName`, `DoingBusinessAs`, `CreationDate`, `ModifiedDate`, `Status` FROM `merchants` WHERE `Deleted` = '0' ORDER BY `CreationDate` Desc");
    while($Merchant = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL)){
            $ID = $Merchant["ID"];
            $LegalName = $Merchant["LegalName"];
            $DoingBusinessAs = $Merchant["DoingBusinessAs"];
            $CreationDate = date('D, M j Y', strtotime($Merchant["CreationDate"]));
            if ($Merchant["ModifiedDate"] != "0000-00-00 00:00:00") { $ModifiedDate = date('D, M j Y', strtotime($Merchant["ModifiedDate"])); } else { $ModifiedDate = ""; }

            if ($Merchant["Status"] == "Inactive") { $Status = "class='warning' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' data-container='body' title='This account is currently marked as Inactive.'"; }

            ...
    }
```

If there is no other route available, I would really appreciate a pointer as to how to implement a "loading icon" while the data is being fetched.

Edit:
Table is INDEXED, here is the table structure:

```
Name    ID  Status  LegalName   DoingBusinessAs BusinessInformation PrincipalInformation    CreationDate    CreatedBy   ModifiedDate    ModifiedBy  Deleted PastDue Delinquent
Type    int(11) tinytext    tinytext    tinytext    text    text    datetime    int(11) datetime    int(11) tinyint(1)  tinyint(1)  tinyint(1)
```

Currently the page takes roughly 4-5 seconds to load. I assumed that this was due to the queries but I have discovered the culprit: the bootstrap [datatables](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables) plugin. It's the **SORTING of the tables** that takes so long, not pulling the data from the server. I'm very sorry for the frustrated people attempting to help me figure this out, I didn't realize I was leaving critical information from my post.

Comment: What is taking so long? Is it the query? 1000 records is nothing.

Comment: Check you indexes and use `EXPLAIN`

Comment: How long does this query take? It shouldn't take more than 1-2 seconds

Comment: Is the table indexed and are you using the indexes?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a database which we don't have access to

Comment: Pagination could also be an option.

Comment: @SurrealDreams How would `SELECT *` make things faster? If anything, this would slow things down by transmitting unneccesary data from additional columns.

Comment: @SurrealDreams - generally the reverse applies, selecting a specified list of fields is normally faster than selecting all fields

Comment: Please add table schema information.

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table? What does an EXPLAIN show for that query?

Comment: You need an index on `Deleted, CreationDate` in order for this query to perform quickly.

Comment: Look at everyone, trying to guess what you need. Next time, try not to spend these guy's time so wastefully and include relevant details in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that this was due to the queries but I have discovered the culprit: the [bootstrap datatables plugin](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables). It's the **SORTING of the tables** that takes so long, not pulling the data from the server.